# How can one qualify for the Imperishable Body ability?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, character-advancement, alchemy

The [Enlightened Scholar](http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/enlightened-scholar) class has this particular class menu ability:

*Note: I'll break down the requirements in bullet points, so its easier to refer to them. the bold faced ones are in the class menus elsewhere, so they don't need to be dealt with*.

> #### [Imperishable Body (Ex)](http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/enlightened-scholar#toc76)
>
> (Requires the Clean Living, **Craft Alchemical Mixture**,  **Excellent Alchemy**, Internal Alchemy, Poison Use, and **Poison Immunity** class abilities and 2 ranks in Craft (Alchemy))
> […]

Poison use is commonplace in other classes (and it hints at forcing the scholar to multiclass) but how to get Craft Alchemical Mixture and Excellent Alchemy baffle me.

Where/how can the ES obtain all the requirements to obtain this ability?

---

**P.S.:** Soapbox all you want about the quality of 3PP elsewhere, but not here, not now. Just a good nice old objective stack answer.

Answer (score 6):

The list of Enlightened Knowledge Abilities on the wiki is not complete. Among the missing abilities are the Wei Tan abilities Craft Alchemical Admixture, Excellent Alchemy, and Poison Use, and the Nei Tan ability Poison Immunity. There is no need to multiclass to get the Imperishable Body ability.

I can't speak to why these features aren't on the wiki, but it looks like the easiest way for an Enlightened Scholar to get the Imperishable Body ability is for that character's player to buy the book.